# WPF set parameters in ListBox child elements

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I would like to change dynamically the width of items in a ListBox.
I've got this XAML for an horizontal list

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox">
     <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
              <UniformGrid IsItemsHost="True" Rows="1" />
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

with following .cs (part of a DragAndDrop code)

```
ObservableCollection<int> _List = new ObservableCollection<int>();

public void Fill(int num)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
    {
       _List.Add(i);
    }
    listBox.ItemsSource = _List;

    Style itemContainerStyle = new Style(typeof(ListBoxItem));
    itemContainerStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(ListBoxItem.AllowDropProperty, true));
    itemContainerStyle.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(ListBoxItem.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(s_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown)));
    itemContainerStyle.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(ListBoxItem.DropEvent, new System.Windows.DragEventHandler(listBox_Drop)));

    listBox.ItemContainerStyle = itemContainerStyle;

}
```

I would like to set the `Rows="2"` dynamically e.g. based on `num` value and change it inside the `.cs` code instead to set this value static in XAML

Comment: In case there is a specific `num` value where you want to switch to two rows, can't you just set `Columns` instead of `Rows`?

Comment: @Clemens also columns could be a right way! The general question is how to change a parameter inside a ListBox from .cs code

Comment: As usual, by data binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `ItemsPanelTemplate` is just a template, but once the `ListBox` has been loaded you could find the `UniformGrid` in the visual tree using the following helper method:

```
private T FindVisualChild<T>(Visual visual) where T : Visual
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(visual); i++)
    {
        Visual child = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(visual, i);
        if (child != null)
        {
            T correctlyTyped = child as T;
            if (correctlyTyped != null)
            {
                return correctlyTyped;
            }

            T descendent = FindVisualChild<T>(child);
            if (descendent != null)
            {
                return descendent;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Once you have a reference to it, you could access its properties, e.g.:

```
System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.UniformGrid grid = FindVisualChild<System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.UniformGrid>(listBox);
if (grid != null)
    grid.Rows = num;
```